# Why is the following sass code giving me an error?

Tags: sass

(.sass)

```
div
    background-color: cyan
```

> Build error: Transform Sass on dart_gol|lib/forms_menu.sass threw
>   error: Invalid CSS after "...und-color: #333": expected "{", was ""
>           on line 6 of standard input

I have Sass installed:
`sass --version`
 "Sass 3.4.22 (Selective Steve)"

I just began using the Sass transformer using [pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_sass_transformer). I got that error; then went back to `--watch .` (using Sass via terminal) to see if it happened there. The error was the same both times.

I'm using a **.sass** extension and it is giving me the problem. I'm using the [Sass Basics](http://sass-lang.com/guide) as a guide.

I did not have a problem when using **.scss**, with the bracket formatting. I'm not sure why **.sass** has a problem.

Comment: I noticed in the Sass Basics guide, it gives the example using .scss which doesn't work without brackets and semi-colons. Once I changed the extension to .sass it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be in the `dart_sass_transformer`. It isn't properly compiling the sass into css.

Turning off the transformer (removing it from the pubspec) and running sass via Terminal is working properly.

The code in question is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It tells you it was expecting {
What you need is:

```
div {
  background-color: cyan
}
```

Comment: That's where my problem is, I'm using **.sass**, not **.scss**. **.sass** doesn't use brackets.

Comment: Then you didn't configure it properly to compile sass instead of scss.

Comment: I have to do that? I thought it just reads the file extension and does things accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you need a compiler like Prepos, grunt or one of the many that exist. Or use ruby sass to watch the file. SASS doesnt require the brackets, but compiled CSS does